# Google BigQuery SQL: Extract data from JSON (list and array) into columns

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have table with json string

```
UserID  json_string
100      [{"id": 77379513, "value": "35.4566", "os_type": null, "amount": "200", "created_at": "2020-08- 
           16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "same'}]
100      [{"id": 77379514, "value": "38.658", "os_type": null, "amount": "100", "created_at": "2020-08- 
         16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "niko'}]
100      [{"id": 77379515, "value": "40.569", "os_type": null, "amount": "150", "created_at": "2020-08- 
         16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "koko'}]
200      [{"id": 77378899, "value": "25.365", "os_type": null, "amount": "100", "created_at": "2020-08- 
         16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "same'}]
200      [{"id": 77378900, "value": "35.898", "os_type": null, "amount": "500", "created_at": "2020-08- 
          16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "niko'}]
200      [{"id": 77378901, "value": "41.258", "os_type": null, "amount": "400", "created_at": "2020-08- 
         16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "koko'}]
```

Finally, I need to convert string to columns:

```
UserID  ID         value    os_type   amount    created_at                  updated_at                  Type_name
100    77379513    35.4566  null    200    2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00    2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00   same
100    77379514    38.658   null    100    2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00    2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:01   niko
100    77379515    40.569   null    150    2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00    2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:02   koko
200    77378899   25.365    null    100    2020-09-16T14:48:27.611-04:01    2020-08-17T14:48:27.611-04:03   same
200    77378900   35.898    null    500    2020-09-16T14:48:27.611-04:02    2020-08-17T14:48:27.611-04:04   niko
200    77378901   41.258    null    400    2020-09-16T14:48:27.611-04:03    2020-08-17T14:48:27.611-04:05   koko
```

First I try to extract JSON from the list:

```
SELECT iUserID,json_extract_array(json_string) as json_array
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Then I get a table like that:

```
UserID                              json_array
100     {"id": 77379513, "value": "35.4566", "os_type": null, "amount": "200", "created_at": "2020-08- 
         16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "same'}
100     {"id": 77379514, "value": "38.658", "os_type": null, "amount": "100", "created_at": "2020-08- 
        16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "niko'}
100     {"id": 77379515, "value": "40.569", "os_type": null, "amount": "150", "created_at": "2020-08- 
        16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "koko'}
200     {"id": 77378899, "value": "25.365", "os_type": null, "amount": "100", "created_at": "2020-09- 
        16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-17T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "same'}
200     {"id": 77378900, "value": "35.898", "os_type": null, "amount": "500", "created_at": "2020-09- 
        16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-17T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "niko'}
200     {"id": 77378901, "value": "41.258", "os_type": null, "amount": "400", "created_at": "2020-09- 
        16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-17T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "koko'}
```

From this step, I try to use a function JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR, but I get an error that this function does not work with the array.
So what is the correct way to extract data to columns?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why store this data in JSON at all? It looks like every entry has the same fields. Why not just make a table with real columns named the same as those fields?

Comment: By the way, I wondered why the lines alternate in color due to the syntax highlighting, and I noticed you used `'` in one place instead of `"`. Keep in mind that these quote characters are not interchangeable in JSON. You must use `"` consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will work for you

```
select UserID, 
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.id') as id,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.value') as value,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.os_type') as os_type,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.amount') as amount,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.created_at') as created_at,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.updated_at') as updated_at,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.Type_name') as Type_name
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(json_extract_array(json_string, '$')) json
```

If apply to sample data in your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 100 UserID, '[{"id": 77379513, "value": "35.4566", "os_type": null, "amount": "200", "created_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "same"}]' json_string union all
  select 100, '[{"id": 77379514, "value": "38.658", "os_type": null, "amount": "100", "created_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "niko"}]' union all
  select 100, '[{"id": 77379515, "value": "40.569", "os_type": null, "amount": "150", "created_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "koko"}]' union all
  select 200, '[{"id": 77378899, "value": "25.365", "os_type": null, "amount": "100", "created_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "same"}]' union all
  select 200, '[{"id": 77378900, "value": "35.898", "os_type": null, "amount": "500", "created_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "niko"}]' union all
  select 200, '[{"id": 77378901, "value": "41.258", "os_type": null, "amount": "400", "created_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.611-04:00", "updated_at": "2020-08-16T14:48:27.836-04:00", "Type_name": "koko"}]' 
)
```

output is

[image]

note: you used `'` in few places instead of `"` so this is "fixed" in above used sample data

In case if you do not have control over value in this table and cannot fix `'` to `"` you can use below instead

```
select UserID, 
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.id') as id,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.value') as value,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.os_type') as os_type,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.amount') as amount,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.created_at') as created_at,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.updated_at') as updated_at,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.Type_name') as Type_name
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(json_extract_array(replace(json_string, "'", '"'), '$')) json
```

note change inside `unnest` which takes care of that issue with `'`